# Bound product of two numbers by sum of their squares

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus, upper-lower-bounds

How can I bound the product of two reals by the sum of their squares?

---

Let $s = a^2 + b^2$ and $p = ab$. Can I find a constant $C$ and an exponent $\alpha$ such that this holds?
$$
p \leq Cs^\alpha
$$
If not, I am interested in any other bound involving the two variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$ab\le \frac{a^2 + b^2}{2}$$
which follows from $(a-b)^2 \ge 0$. I dont think you can do better than this.

Comment: This is best possible - if $a = b$ then you have $ab = (a^2+b^2)/2$ exactly.